# how to check does the asp. net control element exist or not by using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

how to check does the asp. net control element exist or not?
My page actually don't have the element with ID "hyper", but i just want to verify the existence of this.

im looking for the asp.net element with ID "hyper".

so what i have tried is

```
if (("#<%=hyper.ClientID %>").exists())
```

or

```
if (("#<%=hyper.ClientID %>").length>0)
```

but it give me this error

> The name 'hyper' does not exist in the current context

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getElement() {
            if ($('#<%=(hyper.ClientID)%>').length > 0) {
                alert("none!");
            }
            else
                alert("exist!");

        }
</script>

<asp:HyperLink ID="hyper2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="www.facebook.com" >click me</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but your Hyperlink is `hyper2` and your code is looking for `hyper`

Comment: i do it purposely. Supposingly it will alert "none" instead of "exist!". Right?

Comment: well no because your code is first trying to get the client id of a server control

Comment: you must specify hyper2.ClientID inside getElement() for it to work

Comment: @Razvan, can you raise me an example?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the element "hyper" doesn't exists, therefore ".ClientID" returns an error.  You have to check for the element first:

(VB.Net)

```
<% If hyper IsNot Nothing Then %>
   ..: $("<%= hyper.ClientID %>").etc.
<% End If %>
```

(C#)

```
<% if(hyper != null) { %>
  ..: $("<%= hyper.ClientID %>").etc
<% } %>
```

I haven't tried the C# inside of an ASPX page, but the VB.Net works.

Answer (score 0):

try using this,

```
 var Id= "<%=hyper.ClientID %>"
  $('#'+Id).exists()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if ($('#<%=(hyper.ClientID)%>').length > 0 ) {
     // exists
}
```

added in the `$` to the code.

working example here http://jsfiddle.net/h3UUY/

Comment: it give me the same result :(

Comment: what is hyper? could you post your html markup with the .net control?

Answer (score 0):

See this: [What is best method to find a ASP.Net control using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163535/what-is-best-method-to-find-a-asp-net-control-using-jquery)